# Where to download source files / documentation for netbeans cvs client

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I downloaded the netbeans provided CVS API for java from  https://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/downloads/download/org-netbeans-lib-cvsclient.jar

But I cannot find any documentation besides basic usage anywhere.

Where can I download the source files for this library. I tried downloading from netbeans using mercurial client, as explained [here](https://versioncontrol.netbeans.org/javacvs/library/build.html), but even after 3-4 hours and few hundred megs of data transfer, I was not able to find any file!

Comment: So the three documents listed under https://versioncontrol.netbeans.org/javacvs/library/ are not helpful?

Comment: I actually want to know about the different properties and methods present inside some of the classes to find out if they are useful in my application. The guides are basically startup guides, and I was able to use them successfully to get my application running. 
I was hoping, if I would get the source, I could get an insight into what the various properties mean.

But as I said in my question, when I installed Mercurial and tried to download the source, it was going on forever, after 5 hours and almost 750 MBs, there was no file downloaded!